# convert media files

Tags: libavcodec

How can I convert a media file from mp4 (aac and libx264) to mp4 (mp3 and h264) using libavcodec? Can anyone explain what steps I have to do?
As I know, I must decode and then encode audio and video stream to target codec. But how can I save these stream into a mp4 file?

Answer (score 1):

You can write h264 and mp3 using libavcodec, but to write them in an mp4 file you're gonna need libavformat. It's not a simple process, and FFmpeg / Libav libraries are notoriously unintuitive. There are a couple of [examples](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=tree;f=doc/examples;h=9e97a4b3bdd762d0a57c1a37a67a824828fa40d2;hb=HEAD) in their source tree which illustrates the process pretty well. Look for video_encode_example() and audio_encode_example() in decoding_encoding.c. There is also muxing.c.

For beginners, I recommend that you look into ffmpegsource which is a wrapper around FFmpeg / Libav libraries.

I wrote most of the code [here](https://github.com/tuttleofx/TuttleOFX/blob/master/plugins/image/io/FFMpeg/src/ffmpeg/VideoFFmpegWriter.cpp) for a plugin which works with a framework called Tuttle. This should also serve as an example. But don't use it as definitive. Read the documentation that comes with libavcodec and libavformat.